# Custom Buttons in Android: How to get border/edge/frame when I read the background from xml?

Tags: android

Using Android Shapes in xml I have defined a gradient which I use as the background for a button.

This all works nice, but there's no edge surrounding the button. I would like it to look similar to the normal Android button but I need more flexibility to control the color and look.

The shape is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:endColor="#00FF00"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

I would expect the border to be set in the xml. Why doesn't "stroke" fix it? Stroke doesn't seem to do anything.
I checked the Android Developer spec, but couldn't find the answer there:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

I have also looked through all the properties of the Android Button, but as expected there's no such parameter, probably since it's built into the normal Android button. Btw, I checked ImageButton properties too.

Can someone please help?
I know there's the alternative to make an image with proper edges and use an ImageButton, but there really should be a way to fix this programmatically.

Thanks!
Anna

Comment: The xml-code didn't appear in my question above. Can someone please tell me if there are certain tags to use to get the stackoverflow-box I've seen people use for entering code?

Comment: (By the way: To add HTML to your posts you have to indent each line by 4 spaces, same as you would to add code. If you don't, SO's text parser gets confused and your HTML is not displayed.)

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem a while ago. While I don't quite remember why I made each decision, the way I solved it was to use a a shape layer-list. This lets you stack one shape on top of another. For example, the following XML creates a shape with a solid black outline 2px wide, with a 'grey to white to grey' gradient across the middle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:left="1dp"
                android:top="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"/>
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFB0B0B0"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#FFB0B0B0"
                android:angle="315"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

If you want to be able to change that color dynamically at runtime, then things get a ***lot*** messier. Again, the details of why I had to do things a certain way are hazy, but I ended up having to create a custom view class which contained a custom ShapeDrawable. I started off looking at the examples from the ApiDemos app which comes with the SDK - it's a very good resource.

**EDIT:** Another reason your stroke might not be appearing is that you forgot the `android:` before the color="...." bit.

Comment: EDIT: Another reason your stroke might not be appearing is that you forgot the android: before the color="...." bit. That's it!

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem, what i observed is stroke is not applying to button as border at design time but at run time i see the border.

I jst used the following same code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="@color/black" />
    <stroke  android:width="1px" android:color="@color/red" />

</shape>
```

as steve hanley said abvoe you miss the **android:** for the color attribute.

Hope this helps somebody....

Answer (score 3):

Probably much to late, but you have to add an extra ff before the color.

`<stroke android:width="5px" color="#ff000000" />`

Greets

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageButton

```
   <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

Use drawable selector to ImageButton and define your properties

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/startColor"
            android:endColor="@color/endColor"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.5dp"
            android:color="@color/borderColor" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/startColor"
            android:endColor="@color/endColor"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.5dp"
            android:color="@color/borderColor" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/startColor"
            android:endColor="@color/endColor"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.5dp"
            android:color="@color/borderColor" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />

<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_highlighted"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_highlighted"/>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#fdfdfd" android:endColor="#f0f0f0" android:angle="270" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#56390a" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Adding `stroke color #56390a` will solve the problem.