# setting button border which already has a background color

Tags: c#, android, button, border, xamarin.android

I'm absolute beginner to *mono for android*.

Following buttons are created dynamically and assigned some background color.

**How to assign black border with particular thickness to each button?**(refer below screenshot).
Left image is how it looks now and right image is how it should look like.

I've referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912320/custom-buttons-in-android-how-to-get-border-edge-frame-when-i-read-the-backgrou) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626554/android-draw-border-in-imageview/7626628#7626628) on SO, but they doesn't provide the guidance I needed.

**Any help appreciated...**

[image: screen shot]

### EDIT

**Code for setting Button Background :**

```
int[] colors=GetColorForScrips(decimal.Parse(_result.Rows[i]["Change(%)"].ToString ()));
btn.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Rgb(colors[0],colors[1],colors[2]));
```

In **GetColorForScrips()**, I pass a float value, based on which RGB components are returned.

### Note:

1. I'm using *Mono for Android* as my IDE and not *Eclipse*.
2. I'm assigning background color by using above mentioned code snippet.
3. If I use `btn.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Heatmap_Border);`, it gives me error that `can't convert from int to drawable`.
4. If I use `btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.Heatmap_Border);`, it gives me full black screen  i.e. Buttons are clickable, but **not visible**.

**Proposed output:**

As shown in right image above, each button will have a particular background depending on some value. This background is set dynamically.

I also want to use black border across the button.

But I guess the big catch here is I can't use any two from **`btn.SetBackgroundDrawable()`** *OR* **`btn.SetBackgroundResource()`** *OR* **`btn.SetBackgroundColor()`** together.

In such a scenario, only later will be implemented.

Any solution???

### FINAL EDIT

As suggested by one of the users, this works perfectly... (`GetColorForScrips()` returns `RGB` value based on a Float value).

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
drawable.SetStroke(1, Color.Black);
                
int[] colors=GetColorForScrips(decimal.Parse(result.Rows[i]["Change(%)"].ToString ()));
drawable.SetColor(Color.Rgb(colors[0],colors[1],colors[2]))             
btn.SetBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code

create one `button_bg.xml` file in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
  <solid android:color="@color/background_color"/>
  <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/borderline_color" />
</shape>
```

instead of this

```
btn.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Rgb(colors[0],colors[1],colors[2]));
```

use this as your button background like this

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg)`
```

Comment: i am not getting you properly what are you doing her and tell me what do you want clearly..are you setting bg for every button or bg color for layout..

Comment: i got your problem , but your are not getting how to use this code , can you post code how your setting background color for buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can make GradientDrawable programmatically and by using this, you can set border, color in runtime.

here's simple example.

```java
public class And_testActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_view);

    for( int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());

        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setStroke(5, Long.decode("0xff00ffff").intValue() + i * 30);
        drawable.setColor(  Long.decode("0xffff00ff").intValue()+ i * 50);

        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

        view.addView(btn , new LayoutParams(30, 30));   
    }
}
}
```

I used this layout xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/content_view" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thnx very much dude. It's working. But as I'm using Mono Android, my code would be as mentioned in question in end.